# Get inline list items to overflow parent ul

Tags: html, css, list, menu, inline

I have a menu which is made as a list with inline items. While rendering correctly on large screens, elements move underneath the menu when the browser window gets smaller, instead of putting them to the right of the rest of the content.

With `min-width:100%;` for `.drop_menu` I was expecting that the menu would be 100% of the screen width at minimum, but stretch to fit more menu items in the x direction if necessary.

With `width:500px;` for `.drop_menu` it works, but I didn't want to give the menu a fixed width.

The reason that I want the items to overflow in the x direction is because I was going to implement a javascript scroller so the menu would scroll when the mouse cursor gets close to the edge. I can't scroll in the x-direction if there's no x-overflow.

I've created a jsfiddle of my failing menu here: http://jsfiddle.net/j41jfjqL/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are inline, use [`white-space:nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to prevent the list items from appearing on a new line.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ap3zkfn3/)

```
.drop_menu {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.drop_menu > li {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Since you don't want this to occur on the children `li` elements, set the `white-space` property value to `normal`.

Comment: You are a hero. I didn't even know that property existed! Thanks so much